# automated_install.sh: command not found

Tags: linux, github, raspberry-pi3, alexa-skills-kit

I am working on creating an alexa using raspberrypi 3b+ with the blog  https://predictabledesigns.com/how-to-turn-your-raspberry-pi-into-an-amazon-echo-dot-using-alexa/. The github mentioned in the blog no longer exists, so I am using the git repo https://github.com/Superdrac/alexa-avs-sample-app

When I run the command "sudo ~/alexa-avs-sample-app/automated_install.sh" after entering the client ID and everything, I get the following error :

> sudo: /home/pi/alexa-avs-sample-app/automated_install.sh: command not found**

I am quite new to this. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you actually have /bin/bash installed :)
2. Make sure the .sh file is in Unix format (NL only) and not DOS (CR/NL) format:

   $ dos2unix automated_install.sh

Comment: Would - apt-get --reinstall install bash - work?